# Python-Tesseract error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dependencies, tesseract

I've just installed python-tesseract 0.7.6.win32-py2.7.exe on my guest XP(running through virtualbox), and this annoying error showed up:

> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

After checking dependency through dependency walker and added all missing files, these two errors showed up in dependency walker:

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing
>   export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>
> Error: Modules with
>   different CPU types were found.

And of course `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` still did NOT go away.

What do I do now?

Comment: Make sure your OS is 32bit one and try it again.